# Push new data to external JSON file

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

I'm trying to push a new object into an external Javascript document but I am having problems pulling in the JSON file to write to. I have an external, local file called check.json.

How do I call the external json file correctly in node?

```
var newData = JSON.parse(check.json);

newData.check.push({
   cheap: $el.text()
});

check.json = JSON.stringify(newData);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Filesystem](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) object to read and write to files. Specifically, the [`readFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_options_callback) and [`writeFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_filename_data_options_callback) methods.

For example, to read:

```
fs.readFile('/path/to/my/json.json', function (err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var newData = JSON.parse(data);
});
```

---

That said, flat files are not a good format for storing data and being accessed like a database. You can run into race conditions and lose data. You would be better off with a real database that will take case of that sort of thing for you.

[SQLite](http://blog.modulus.io/nodejs-and-sqlite) gives you a simple file (but puts lots of protection in around it). If you really wanted JSON as the storage format then you could look at something like [couchDB](https://github.com/dscape/nano).

Comment: Nice answer, I was not aware of that option.

Comment: What I want to do is store some data from a function and check if it's already in the JSON file. If it's in the JSON already, the function will exit out. If it's not, the function will continue. The problem I've found with readFile / writeFile was that I was constantly overwriting the data in the JSON file, rather than adding to it, which is my anticipated behaviour. I have implemented a test of the above and found my data being overridden. With this in mind could you offer a solution what adds a new object to the JSON? Cheers @Quentin.

Comment: 1. Read from the JSON file. 2. Parse the JSON into a data structure. 3. Add your data to that data structure. 4. Convert that data to JSON. 5. Write to the file. (Or use a real database as I recommended earlier).