# How to append object to external JSON file using JavaScript native (Vanilla Js)

Tags: javascript, json

Is there any method to add object to external JSON file using JavaScript ?

I have a JSON file named datas.json has content like this:

```
{
"Employes":[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "fullName": "Test Test"
        }
    ],
"Infos":[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "address": "Test Test test test test",
            "employes": 1
        }
  ]
}
```

I try to do it, I can push to the current array, but on file I was blocked.

```
function pushJSONFile(){
    fetchJSONFile(function(data){
        console.log(data.Employes);
        data.Employes.push({
            "id": 2,
            "fullName": "Test Test 2"
        });
        jsonStr = JSON.stringify(data.Employes);
    });
}
```

So, is there any method to push new object to this JSON file using native JavaScript (Vanilla JS)?

For more explain, I want when I push this new object :

```
data.Employes.push({
   "id": 2,
   "fullName": "Test Test 2"
});
```

If I open my datas.json file will be like this :

```
{
"Employes":[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "fullName": "Test Test"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "fullName": "Test Test 2"
        }
    ],
"Infos":[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "address": "Test Test test test test",
            "employes": 1
        }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You mean you want to write the edited JSON file back to the file system?

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33118774/push-new-data-to-external-json-file

Comment: you want to write the data back in file?where is this file located? do you have write access?

Comment: I edited the post to more explain, I want when I push new object, this will be added on my JSON File ( located on localhost, I can access to it from localhost/datas.json ). " I'm sorry for my bad English "

Comment: Are you using NodeJS? Or is this running in a web browser? Please clarify what you mean with 'vanilly JS' as the answer will differ based on the platform.

Comment: @Mathyn I use native JavaScript (Vanilla JS)

Comment: @sayou Yes you mentioned that already... What I mean is is this code part of a website or do you run it using something like NodeJS?

Comment: @Mathyn no, it's just a part of a website, I don't use any server language, I want just to use Javascript